# Splitting a loop into the same equal parts each time

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist

I have created an app that recieves orders and i want to be able to cycle 4 sets of orders so each device can choose what set of orders it sees. I want to split the orders by the order_id so

```
a: 1 5 9  13 ect
b: 2 6 10 14 ect
c: 3 7 11 15 ect
d: 4 8 12 16 ect
```

I recieve the orders through a loop but can change to a list of array lists if nessecary. I have tried a couple ways to get the result im after but have had no luck. Thank you in advance

EDIT (Rough idea of what i want)

```
//Data from Json
         for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
         try {
         JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         // Pulling items from the array
         final int objectsItem = oneObject.getInt("order_id");

     if(checkboxA == checked)
     {
     //Show orders 1,5,9,13 ect
     }
     if(checkboxB == checked)
     {
     //Show orders 2,6,10,14 ect
     }
     if(checkboxA == checked)
     {
     //Show orders 3,7,11,15 ect
     }
     if(checkboxA == checked)
     {
     //Show orders 4,8,12,16 ect
     }
     }
```

`

This way i can show all orders, all parts of orders, so the orders can be equally split between many devices without interacting with each other - Hope this makes more sense

Comment: Please provide some code; to show how exactly data is coming in; and what you intend to do about it. So far; I have **no** clue what you intend to do. Maybe that answer suggesting a map is correct, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Map? You can set every order_id as the key for an entry and all orders as the value of the entry (for example List of orders).

For example:

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> map;
```

Than you can get a certain order_id with:

```
List<Integer> orders = map.getValue('a');

for (Integer order : orders) {
    //do logic here
}
```